# Binding Data text field, Data value field to asp:Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a helper function to Bind Drop down list in asp.net.
See my function:

```
  public void BindDDL(string query, DropDownList DDL)
    {
        List<Issuetype> obj = new List<Issuetype>();
        Issuetype iss = new Issuetype();
        iss.DeptId = 1;
        iss.Issue = "SSS";
        iss.IssuetypeId = 4;
        obj.Add(iss);
        //BALissue Bl = new BALissue();
        //List<Issuetype> objSource = null;
        //objSource = Bl.Bind_issuetypes(query);
        DDL.DataSource = obj;
        DDL.DataValueField = Convert.ToString(obj[0]);
        DDL.DataTextField = Convert.ToString(obj[1]);
        DDL.DataBind();

    }
```

In this way if i send the query name and Dropdownlist id to the function, drop down should be binded by the List of Issuetype entity, You can see the properties of Issuetype in code.

But however i am not able to Set the DataValueField and DataTextField correctly. Every time it is saying index out of range.

Comment: you can pass the DataValueField and DataTextField as parameters to the BindDDL() method and use them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no `obj[1]` in your code because you have only one item in the `obj` list, so at

```
DDL.DataTextField = Convert.ToString(obj[1]);
```

this line  you will get the exception

Instead you can use

```
   DDL.DataValueField = "Issue"; 
   DDL.DataTextField = "IssuetypeId";
```

And to get property names use `Reflection`

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace  
// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
// sort properties by name
Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
        delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });
// write property names
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
  Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: I want to use this function for different lists, is there a way to get the property names by index

Comment: @user3452210 you can pass the DataValueField and DataTextField as parameters to the BindDDL() method and use them.

Comment: i can do it but i am looking for a simple solution , where we can get the property names in list.

Comment: so do you want assign the values for DDL.DataValueField, DDL.DataTextField from the property names of the class?

Comment: yep..every time i call this method returned list will contains an ID and NAME fields ....SO i am thinking to bind them to ValueField and TextField respectively

Comment: use reflection to get the property name like............... using System.Reflection;  

// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
// sort properties by name
Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
        delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
  Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}

Comment: Did you got your answer by using reflection?

Comment: I havent tried it, i ll try later...i am sending Datatextfield,valuefields as parameters...

Comment: Could you plz give the tutorial link of d reflection wch yu gave above??

Answer (score 1):

`DataValueField` and `DataTextField` should be names of the field in your collection, not values from the collection.

```
    DDL.DataSource = obj;
    DDL.DataValueField = "Issue"; //example choose what is needed
    DDL.DataTextField = "IssuetypeId"; //example choose what is needed
    DDL.DataBind();
```

The exception is thrown because in your collection you have 1 item, but you try to put second item(not exist) in `DataTextField`. But this is not relevant if you fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the key and value fields. In your case, you're adding one item to list but trying to access the second (non-existent) item while trying to specify the value: `Convert.ToString(obj[1])`.

What you probably want instead is this:

```
DDL.DataValueField = "IssuetypeId";
DDL.DataTextField = "Issue";
```